# Locally Free Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a locally noetherian scheme and $F$ is a coherent sheaf, I want to show the following equivalence:

$F$ is locally free iff its stalk is a free $O_{X,p}$-module for every $p$ in $X$.

=> follows from the definition of locally free.

<= is difficult for me: I don't see how to combine finite-type condition on $F$ with locally noetherian property.

Comment: In fact it suffices that $X$ is an arbitrary ringed space and that $F$ is of finite presentation; of course, Georges' proof does not work in this generality. The basic idea of the general proof is that $\mathcal{H}om(F,\mathcal{O}_X^n)_x \cong Hom(F_x,\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^n)$ ([by the presentation condition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/why-doesnt-hom-commute-with-taking-stalks/645385#645385])), so that an isomorphism $F_x \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^n$ lifts to an isomorphism $F|_U \to \mathcal{O}_X|_U^n$ on some open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the name indicates, "locally free" is a local concept.
So we can assume that $X=Spec(A)$, the  affine scheme associated to the *noetherian* ring $A$, and $F=\tilde M$, the coherent sheaf associated to the finitely generated $A$-module $M$.

The sheaf $F=\tilde M$ is locally free if and only if the module $M$ is projective.
And a finitely generated   module $M$ over a noetherian ring $A$ is projective if and only if all its localizations $M_{\mathfrak p} \;  ( \mathfrak p \in Spec(A)$ are $A_{\mathfrak p}$-free modules.
Since at  a point $p\in  X$ corresponding to the prime $\mathfrak p \in Spec(A)$ we have $\mathcal O_{X,x}=A_{\mathfrak p}$ and $ F_p=M_{\mathfrak p}$,  we see that indeed freeness of all stalks of $F$ implies local  freeness of the given coherent sheaf $F$.

Comment: Why is $F$ locally free iff $M$ is projective?

Comment: @rmdmc89  There is a well-known equivalence of categories, you can see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645767/source-coherent-locally-free-sheaves-and-projective-modules).