# Source: Coherent locally free sheaves and projective modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, coherent-sheaves

What is a good and very quick and concise article for the proof of the equivalence of the categories of locally free sheaves on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and finitely generated projective $A$-modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chapter II, §5.2 in:

> N. Bourbaki, *Elements of mathematics. Commutative algebra.* Hermann, Paris, 1972. Translated from the French.

Alternatively, you can always consult the stacks project for these basics. In this case, it's [Tag 00NV](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NV).

Comment: Dear Martin: without any disrespect to your country, the publisher of the Bourbaki volume you mention is Hermann, not Germann. Apart from that I can only second you on this excellent reference.

Comment: Oh, this wasn't intended :). G is next to H.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much guys :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not read [Serre's crystal-clear article](https://eudml.org/doc/111153) which introduced this equivalence?
As Gauss said: "Read the masters".

Comment: Thanks I almost forget how much of a pleasure it is to read from Serre :)

Comment: Dear CSA: ...and how much of a pleasure it is to read your so true comment !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, sorry for commenting on an old thread, but the link to the paper is broken. I believe [this](http://archive.numdam.org/article/SD_1957-1958__11_2_A9_0.pdf) is the paper Georges had in mind. In case the link breaks again, the name of the article is "Modules projectifs et espaces fibres a fibre vectorielle".

Comment: Thanks @aytio: that's indeed the article, from Séminaire Dubreil 1957-1958. I have modified my link. Just to be on the safe side, [here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiItu-64JnTAhVI0YMKHWXNDssQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.numdam.org%2Farticle%2FSD_1957-1958__11_2_A9_0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGShvge1xc22LtOm0_YsZDC8v9jHQ&sig2=xKjmUaY3RIkUUfbiW_AXyw) is a different link to the same article. And [yet another one](http://bardenas.ujf-grenoble.fr/item?id=SD_1957-1958__11_2_A9_0).