# A question of sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G$ be sheaves. $\mathscr{H}\hspace{-3pt}om$ does not commute with taking stalks. More precisely: It is
not true in general that $\mathscr{H}\hspace{-3pt}om(\mathscr F, \mathscr G)_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{H}\hspace{-3pt}om(\mathscr F_p,\mathscr G_p)$.

How to verify the above fact?

Comment: Perhaps look at something with no global sections?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/why-doesnt-hom-commute-with-taking-stalks).